# Web.config Rewrite rule in some cases, otherwise leave original

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Can somebody help me write Rewrite rule that would basically say this:

If URL has "siteA" in it, but only if continues with "wp-admin, wp-content or wp-includes" then remove "siteA". In all other cases, leave "siteA" in URL.

e.g

domain.com/siteA/hello -> **remains** domain.com/siteA/hello

domain.com/siteA/wp-admin/some.css -> **rewrites to** domain.com/wp-admin/some.css

domain.com/siteA/wp-content/some.css -> **rewrites to** domain.com/wp-content/some.css

domain.com/siteA/wp-includes/some.css -> **rewrites to** domain.com/wp-includes/some.css

I tried several options, but I obviously suck at regex and url-rewriting; one of those tries:

```
        <rule name="Custom: remove subsite from resources paths">
          <match url="^siteA/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
```

Tried also

```
            <rule name="Custom: remove subsite from resources paths">
              <match url="^siteA/(wp-(content|admin|includes))/(*)"/>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}{R:3}"/>
            </rule>
```

and also

```
    <rule name="Custom: remove subsite from resources paths">
      <match url="^siteA/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}{R:3}"/>
    </rule>
```

---

This is my complete rules node (generated by Wordpress due to the multisite).

So the thing is, it generates

domain.com/siteA/wp-includes/some.css

instead of

domain.com/wp-includes/some.css

So I need to lose the "siteA" when it comes to wp-includes etc. In other cases (regular post domain.com/siteA/regularPost ) should remain as is.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>                 
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Did you try with `<action type="Redirect"`?

Comment: I don't think my regex in match url parameter, and my action url parameter are fine..

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/m8EvzX/1, it seems to work.

Comment: So why doesn't the whole thing doesn't work? Is there a problem with the node itself (action url or something?) BTW I tried Redirect as you suggested, same thing.

Comment: Is there any other rule executed before this one that stops processing?

Comment: I'll edit my question. It is actually a block of rules, it is Wordpress Multisite problem. I just edited it. Wordpress rule 4 looks like it should do the trick, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want. According to your problem description, the several options you have tried almost achieve your goal. I tested it and it had some problems. So I improve it to rewrite siteA.

```
 <rule name="remove siteA">
                <match url="siteA/(wp-(content|admin|includes))/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" />
 </rule>
```

The process of rewrite can check in failed request tracing.
[image]

Comment: I believe you solved the problem (I roughly tested it, I still need to test it some more). As I'm not into regex, I didn't know what I was writing, more like try-and-catch.

Comment: Actually, this ^ sign is confusing, because sometimes it means NOT and sometimes "starts with"